# BackboneJS how to turn text URLs into clickable links

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a Backbone App where I fetch Twitter tweets through an API which returns the result as string. What I need is to make the http in the string clickable. How can I achieve this?

Here is the text string:

```
 Who does John wish he could have sung with over the span of his career? See the video answer here! http://t.co/pbPXaDkGEJ
```

and I want it to be like

```
<span>Who does John wish he could have sung with over the span of his career? See the video answer here! <a href="http://t.co/pbPXaDkGEJ"> click here</a></span>
```

I tried to do something like:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
   var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
   return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

but that didnt work...

**[UPDATE]**

Ok, I'm gonna add my Backbone View:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var ArtistTwitter = App.module();

    ArtistTwitter.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        className: 'actweets',
        template: 'artistTwitter',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render);
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.collection ? this.collection.toJSON() : [];
        }
    });
    ArtistTwitter.ArtistTwitterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return '/myproject/index.php/api/social_feeds/fetchNewTweet/' + this.artist_id;
        }
    });

    return ArtistTwitter;
}
```

I tried to add the above mentioned replacement code inside an `afterRender`-function but that didnt work...

Any suggestion is welcome...

Comment: Here's a good answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7123542/536610

Comment: Ok was checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links/7123542#7123542 - regarding BackboneJS, should I run this in `initialize` or `afterRender` or..???

Answer (score 0):

Well it replaces links correctly but you need to modify it a bit to get your expected output. If I understand correctly, you only need to change sencond $1 to the static text 'click here' to get the desired output:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>click here</a>"); 
}
```

This will return:

```
replaceURLWithHTMLLinks("Who does John wish he could have sung with over the span of his career? See the video answer here! http://t.co/pbPXaDkGEJ ")

"Who does John wish he could have sung with over the span of his career? See the video answer here! <a href='http://t.co/pbPXaDkGEJ'>click here</a> "
```

UPDATE:

In this case I think you should be able to get what you want by adding repleaceURLWithHTMLLinks to your **model view** (the view you pasted is for your collection) and implementing render method:

```
ArtistTwitterItemView.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    replaceURLWithHTMLLinks: function(text) {
       var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
       return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>click here</a>"); 
    },

    // something like this (copy paste will not work but it might get you on the track): 
    // it looks like this should in be a model view 
    // in collections view you should iterate through your collection and call render for each item
    // in the case for model view call replaceURLWithHTMLLinks before rendering:
    render: function(){
       var data = this.model.toJSON();
       _.extend(data, { replacedText: replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(data.text) });
       var html = _.template($(this.template), data);
       this.$el.html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok any idea how to implement this in BackboneJS? The string with the text-link actually comes from an API, so do I have to add this piece of code inside the View in an `afterRender`-function?

Comment: depending on your setup you can either add this function as a helper method and use it your templates or you could add it view (or model) and call it to transform model attributes before passing them to  the template for rendering

Comment: Hmm Ok, I updated my question and added my View to make it more clear. Transforming sounds interesting but I'm pretty new to BackboneJS, so I cant really follow you